# Return LINQ query to DataTable .NET 3.5?

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, .net-3.5, datatable

I want to query two `DataTables` (populated by parsing Excel files) using LINQ and join them on a matching field, "UPC", as follows:

```
Dim query = From c In dt.AsEnumerable() _
Join r In dtUnits.AsEnumerable() _
On c.Field(Of String)("UPC") Equals r.Field(Of String)("UPC") _
Select New With {.UPC = r.Field(Of String)("UPC")}
```

Additionally, I want to copy this LINQ query result to a DataTable.  I found a [method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386921.aspx) `CopyToDataTable()`, but it is in .NET 4.5, and our server only supports .NET 3.5.

What can I do to emulate this functionality in VB .NET 3.5?

Thank you!

Comment: It is available in .NET 3.5 also. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.copytodatatable(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: That's strange, it's not appearing in Intellisense, and I believe I have the correct references and imports--`Imports System.Linq` and `Imports System.Data`--am I missing something?

Comment: @user1496816: It's not available in Intellisense because it's an extension for `IEnumerabley<DataRow>` and you're selecting an `IEnumerable<anonymous type>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`CopyToDataTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386921%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) is already there since .NET 35. But the problem is that you want to create a `DataTable` "from the scratch" from an anonymous type. That doesn't work.

`CopyToDataTable` is an extension for `IEnumerable<DataRow>` only. So you either have to select **one** `DataRow` from your joined `DataTables`:

```
Dim query = From c In dt.AsEnumerable() _
            Join r In dtUnits.AsEnumerable() _
            On c.Field(Of String)("UPC") Equals r.Field(Of String)("UPC") _
            Select c
Dim table = query.CopyToDataTable()
```

or use [this `ObjectShredder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669096.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) which uses reflection, hence is not the most efficient way([C# implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9259348/284240)).

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you.  Because I am not too concerned with performance, I think I'm going to use the `ObjectShredder`method.  This is a little above my head, though.  I added both `DataSetLinqOperators.vb` and `ObjectShredder.vb` to my project, but I don't know how to implement them.

Comment: You need to add the extension methods: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669096.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this article:

http://codecorner.galanter.net/2009/12/17/grouping-ado-net-datatable-using-linq/

You can use `.toDataTable` method, but only if your LINQ Query returns actual DataTable rows. For a custom type you can use attached to the article code to perform the same.

Answer (score -1):

Pls read this article LINQ TO DATATABLE in WCF ,connecting to Adventure Database.

Datasets doesnot implement IEnumerable/IQueryable interface,.

So pls read this article.

http://www.wnewsone.com/tutorials/wcf/ShowArticle.aspx?articleid=20143