# DataTable Error - Can't CopyToDataTable()

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, ado.net

Suppose I have the following 2 datatables:

```
Table1:                               Table2:
Col1:                                 Col1:         Col2:
1                                     1             a
2                                     2             b
2                                     3             c
3                                     4             d
3                                     5             e
4                                     6             f
                                      7             g
```

And I want a simple Linq query that creates a third DataTable based upon a join between the two and giving distinct values - Looking as follows:

```
Result:
Col1:       Col2:
1           a
2           b
3           c
4           d
```

I assumed this would do it:

```
Dim Result as DataTable = (From dr1 As DataRow In Table1.AsEnumerable
             Join dr2 As DataRow In Table2.AsEnumerable
             On dr1.Field(Of Double)("Col1") Equals dr2.Field(Of Double)("Col1")
             Select New With {
                                 .Col1 = dr1.Field(Of Double)("Col1"),
                                 .Col2 = dr2.Field(Of String)("Col2")
                             }).Distinct.CopyToDataTable
```

But I'm getting a host of different errors regardless what I try...

My first error is that `CopyToDataTable` method is not a member of `System.Generic.IEnumerable`

When I remove that, and leave it as:

```
Dim Result = (From dr1 As DataRow In Table1.AsEnumerable
             Join dr2 As DataRow In Table2.AsEnumerable
             On dr1.Field(Of Double)("Col1") Equals dr2.Field(Of Double)("Col1")
             Select New With {
                                 .Col1 = dr1.Field(Of Double)("Col1"),
                                 .Col2 = dr2.Field(Of String)("Col2")
                             }).Distinct
```

It runs, but it doesn't filter the results down to a unique list - It leaves all the `col1` values in there from `Table1`.

I'm trying to understand Linq, but am obviously missing something - Can someone please explain to me what's going on here and how to fix this??

---

As an addition onto @Magnus' solution, for anyone who comes across this kind of problem in the future, the `CopyToDataTable` method for an IEnumerable of Anonymous Type (as Magnus pointed out was what I gave in this question) can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669096.aspx) and an implementation of it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386921.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `Key` identifier to the properties on [Anonymous Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384767.aspx) in VB. (In C# all properties are key properties) Only the values of key properties are compared in order to determine whether two instances are equal, and you need this for `Distinct()` to work.

```
Select New With {
                 Key .Col1 = dr1.Field(Of Double)("Col1"),
                 Key .Col2 = dr2.Field(Of String)("Col2")
                }
```

As for getting `CopyToDataTable` to work on anonymous types check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9259348/468973).

Comment: Thank you!! - The first problem of duplicates being brought back was solved with the `Key` identifier, but I still can't get the `CopyToDataTable` to work... :(

Comment: `CopyToDataTable()` only works on `IEnumerable(of DataRow)` and you have IEnumerable of an anonymous type.

Comment: Again, @Magnus, THANKS!! - That makes sense... the thing that got me confused is MSDN documentation like here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386921.aspx - How do they manage to do it in the 3rd example? - Am I missing something???

Comment: ... I apologize - I read it again, they offer a routine to do the work for you... @Magnus, thank you very much!!!!