# Can't copy LINQ result into datatable

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

Below is my LINQ query:

```
Dim JoinedResult = From t1 In temp.AsEnumerable() _
                   Group Join t2 In tbCity.AsEnumerable() _
                   On t1.Field(Of String)("City") Equals t2.Field(Of String)("city_name") _
                   Into RightTableResults = Group _
                   From t In RightTableResults.DefaultIfEmpty
                   Select New With 
                   {
                        .ID = t1.Item("ID"), 
                        .CID = If(t Is Nothing, 
                        1,  
                        t.Item("city_gid"))
                   }
```

How can I copy values from  "JoinedResult" to a datatable?

Note:

1. I'm not getting `JoinedResult.CopyToDataTable()`
2. I don't want to use a loop

Answer (score 3):

[`CopyToDataTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386921%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) is already there since .NET 3.5. But the problem is that you want to create a `DataTable` "from the scratch" from an anonymous type. That doesn't work.

`CopyToDataTable` is an extension for `IEnumerable<DataRow>` only. So you either have to select **one** `DataRow` from your joined `DataTables`:

```
Dim query =  From t1 In temp.AsEnumerable() _
             Group Join t2 In tbCity.AsEnumerable() _
             On t1.Field(Of String)("City") Equals t2.Field(Of String)("city_name") Into RightTableResults = Group 
             From t In RightTableResults.DefaultIfEmpty
             Select t1
Dim table = query.CopyToDataTable()
```

or use [this `ObjectShredder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669096.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) which uses reflection, hence is not the most efficient way([C# implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9259348/284240)).

Apart from this, why do you need the `DataTable` at all? You could also use the anonymous type as DataSource or create a custom class which you can initialize from the query result.

**Edit**: You can also create a custom `DataTable` with the columns you need, for example(from your comment):

```
Dim tbTemp As New DataTable
tbTemp.Columns.Add("ID")
tbTemp.Columns.Add("CID")

Dim query = From t1 In temp.AsEnumerable()
            Group Join t2 In tbCity.AsEnumerable() On
            t1.Field(Of String)("City") Equals t2.Field(Of String)("city_name")
            Into RightTableResults = Group
            From t In RightTableResults.DefaultIfEmpty
            Select New With {.ID = t1.Item("ID"), .City_Gid = t.Item("city_gid")}
For Each x In query
    tbTemp.Rows.Add(x.ID, x.City_Gid)
Next
```

Comment: i'm not getting "city_gid"(from t) if i use select t1. i need value t.Item("city_gid") also

Comment: @balaji: Why do you need the `DataTable`? Maybe it would be sufficient to use the `IEnumerable<anonymoustype>` in a `foreach` or you could create a custom class and a `List<customclass>`. The `ObjectShredder` does also work for any type(even anonymous) but is more difficult and not the most efficient.

Comment: bcz i need to add few more colums with datatable and need to insert the datatable into database(using bulkcopy)

Comment: @balaji: Then create a destination DataTable with all columns you need and add the rows in a `foreach` from the result of the query.

Comment: i got solution but this may be silly or stupid  Dim tbTemp As New DataTable  tbTemp.Columns.Add("ID") tbTemp.Columns.Add("CID")  Dim JoinedResult = From t1 In temp.AsEnumerable() _
                   Group Join t2 In tbCity.AsEnumerable() _
                   On t1.Field(Of String)("City") Equals t2.Field(Of String)("city_name") _
                   Into RightTableResults = Group _
                   From t In RightTableResults.DefaultIfEmpty
                  Select tbTemp.LoadDataRow(New Object() {t1.Item("ID"),t.Item("city_gid")) datatable=JoinedResult.CopyToDataTable()

Comment: @balaji: Not exactly, i've edited my answer to show what i've meant.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23561/discussion-between-balaji-and-tim-schmelter)