# LINQ store result of join in a DataTable

Tags: .net, linq, join, datatable

Is there a way in linq to join two DataTables and store the result in another DataTable? And I mean a **DataTable** not the hierarchical form that group join creates.

Here is the code for group join that i have got so far. Which works, but I don't understand what to do with the result.

```
var temp = from t1 in table1
           join t2 in table2
           on t1.Field<string>("a")
           equals t2.Field<string>("b") into t
           select t;
```

And also, how does one use the hierarchical form created by group join anyway?

Comment: A similar question i've answered yesterday: [Can't copy LINQ result into DataTable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578235/cant-copy-linq-result-into-datatable)

Answer (score 0):

That LINQ query should give you a collection of DataRow objects, correct?  You could try [using this approach on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122511/simple-way-to-convert-datarow-array-to-datatable) to convert the rows into a new table.

Comment: The type is `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Data.DataRow>> {System.Linq.Enumerable.GroupJoinIterator<System.Data.DataRow,System.Data.DataRow,string,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Data.DataRow>>}`

Comment: I'm not sure why it's double enumerable from that query, and that is the problem. You could try to get around that by doing at the end t.SelectMany(i => i) and see if that resolves the problem.  SelectMany is supposed to flatten a resultset.  Not sure if that will work.