# error in binding datatable to database by linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datatable

i exacly copy from msdn but the following code gives me error

```
    The type 'AnonymousType#1' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method
'System.Data.DataTableExtensions.CopyToDataTable<T>   (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>,
 System.Data.DataTable, System.Data.LoadOption)'.  There is no implicit reference conversion from
 'AnonymousType#1' to 'System.Data.DataRow'.
```

my code:

```
Item[] items = new Item[] 
                                {
                                    new Book{Id = 1, Price = 13.50, Genre = "Comedy", Author = "Gustavo Achong"}, 
                                  new Book{Id = 2, Price = 8.50, Genre = "Drama", Author = "Jessie Zeng"},
                                  new Movie{Id = 1, Price = 22.99, Genre = "Comedy", Director = "Marissa Barnes"},
                                  new Movie{Id = 1, Price = 13.40, Genre = "Action", Director = "Emmanuel Fernandez"}
                                };

            // Create a table with a schema that matches that of the query results.            
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            dt1.Columns.Add("Price", typeof(int));
            dt1.Columns.Add("Genre", typeof(string));

            var query = from i in items
                        where i.Price > 9.99
                        orderby i.Price
                        select new { i.Price, i.Genre };

            query.CopyToDataTable(dt1, LoadOption.PreserveChanges);
```

how to make it workabe?

Comment: Try to rename the extension(f.e. `CopyAnyToDataTable`), maybe that's a naming conflicht with the `DataTableExtensions.CopyToDataTable` extension method.

Comment: @TimSchmelter no the type argument has to be compatible with DataRow see the constraint on T: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Selman22: i assume that OP is using Microsoft's `ObjectShredder` class which allows to use `CopyToDataTable` with any type. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669096(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: i didn't get it.Anyone can explain with working code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, place it in a static helper class and this will allow you to call ToDataTable(); on the items.

```
public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> data)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        foreach (var prop in data.First().GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(prop.Name);
        }

        foreach (T entry in data)
        {
            List<object> newRow = new List<object>();
            foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
            {
                var val = entry.GetType().GetProperty(dc.ColumnName).GetValue(entry, null);
                newRow.Add(val);
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(newRow.ToArray());
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

Comment: @decoder If you have the above in a separate static class, you can call i like so    `DataTable dt1 = query.ToDataTable();`

Answer (score 1):

> I exacly copy from msdn...

Are you trying to implement Microsofts [`ObjectShredder<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669096(v=vs.110).aspx)-class which allows to use `CopyToDataTable` with any type?

Then try to rename the extension(f.e. `CopyAnyToDataTable`), it could be a naming conflict with the `DataTableExtensions.CopyToDataTable` extension method which allows only `DataRow`s.

Some time ago i also had that issue, here's a similar question:

[Exception using CopyToDataTable with "new {..}" LINQ query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072120/exception-using-copytodatatable-with-new-linq-query)